# How to get the value of the button on click in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 4 buttons each with unique value.I am getting undefined in console log with current code.

HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="parcel-btn weight-option" value="25" (click)="onItemSelector()">
<button type="submit" class="parcel-btn weight-option" value="50" (click)="onItemSelector()">
<button type="submit" class="parcel-btn weight-option" value="250" (click)="onItemSelector()">
<button type="submit" class="parcel-btn weight-option" value="100" (click)="onItemSelector()">
```

Typescript

```
onItemSelector() {
  const weightSelector = this.elm.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.weight-option').value;
  console.log(weightSelector);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

Pass the value to the onItemSelector function

```
   <button type="submit" class="parcel-btn weight-option" (click)="onItemSelector(25)">
```

Get the value in ts

```
onItemSelector(value :any) {
console.log(value);
}
```